# nested calls to constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++11, nested, c++14, constexpr

Following (generic) situation:

I am trying to call another `constexpr` member-function within a class, but I get the error that `'this' is not a constant expression`. The question I now have is (as I am new to the `constexpr` idiom), is if such a use-case is not allowed. Otherwise, how would I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>

class cc
{
public:
    cc()=default;
    ~cc()=default;

    // public method to call th eprivate constexpr functions
    template<int varbase>
    constexpr void doSomething()
    {
        static_assert(varbase>0, "varbase has to be greater zero");
        // nested call to constexpr functions
        char x=testM2<testM1<varbase>()>();
    }

private:

    template<int var1>
    constexpr int testM1()
    {
     int temp=var1;
     return (++temp);
    }

    template<int var2>
    constexpr char testM2()
    {
        int temp=var2;
        if (temp==2)
            return 'A';
        else
            return 'B';
    }
};

int main()
{
    cc obj;
    obj.doSomething<1>();
    return 0;
}
```

[Run the above example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b89175793a78264d)

Comment: `constexpr` functions can be called in a non-`constexpr` context. I suspect they can't be used as template arguments.

Comment: Just mark `testM1` and `testM2` as `static`. What you are trying to do is like `constexpr void foo(int i) { std::array<int, i> arr; }`. This is not allowed.

Comment: The problem is that every instance of `cc` will have its own version of `doSomething()`, `testM1()` and `testM2()`. To solve it, the compiler will apply `this` in front of all the functions, to identify which instance of `cc` you are trying to refer to. `this` is not a constant expression. It is evaluated at runtime. To solve this problem, either move your `constexpr` functions outside the class, or mark these functions as `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `constexpr` does not mean "this function can only be called at compile time".  It means "this function may be called both at compile and run time".

```
    char x=testM2<testM1<varbase>()>();
```

If called at run time, the value of `this` is not a compile time constant.  So the result of a `constexpr` method call is not a compile time value, so its result cannot be used as a template argument.

If you are not using `this` (as you appear not to be) then marking `testM2` etc. as `static` fixes your problem.  If you are using `this` then there isn't a simple workaround; there is no way to say "this function will only be called at compile time".  Any workaround will depend on details of what you are doing with `this` and the return value, if even possible.  Write a new question with those details added.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every instance of `cc` will have its own version of `doSomething()`, `testM1()` and `testM2()`.
To solve it, the compiler will apply `this` in front of all the functions, to identify which instance of `cc` you are trying to refer to.

`this` is not a constant expression. It is evaluated at runtime.
That is why you are getting the error : `'this' is not a constant expression`

To solve this problem, either move your `constexpr` functions outside the class, or mark these functions as `static`.

Here is a working revision of your code, which will work in C++11 as well.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int var1>
constexpr int testM1() // move these functions outside, if they use no data of class cc
{
    return int{var1 + 1};
}

template<int var2>
constexpr char testM2()
{
    return (var2 == 2) ? 'A' : 'B';
}

class cc
{
public:
    cc()=default;
    ~cc()=default;

    // public method to call the private constexpr functions
    template<int varbase>
    static constexpr void doSomething() 
    {
        /* if you want to keep it inside class, mark it `static` 
           so that the compiler understands that it will be shared by all instances. */
        static_assert(varbase>0, "varbase has to be greater zero");
        // nested call to constexpr functions
        constexpr char x = testM2<testM1<varbase>()>(); // preferably x should be `constexpr`
    }
};

int main()
{
    cc obj;
    obj.doSomething<2>();
    return 0;
}
```